# Вывести циклом значение дополнительных полей WP

Tags: php, wordpress

Пользуюсь плагином "types" для WP. требуется из админки добавлять и удалять телефоны на сайте. Создал дополнительное поле, разрешил ему множественные значения (номеров телефонов может быть несколько одновременно). При попытке вывести поле получаю все значения в кучу, вывожу вот так:

```
echo types_render_field('tel');
```

Т.е. если будет 2 поля с номерами "1111" и "2222", то выведется "11112222". Раньше проблема решалась разделителем:

```
types_render_field('tel', array (separator => '<br>'));
```

Но теперь нужно сделать что бы каждый номер телефона был завернут в кликабельную ссылку:

```
<a href = 'tel:1111'>1111</a> <br> <a href = 'tel:2222'>2222</a>
```

и разделитель уже не спасает. Может кто знает как разделить значения что бы их можно было циклом вывести к примеру

Comment: <a href="<?= echo types_render_field('tel'); ?>">types_render_field('tel', array (separator => '</a><br>'));  как вариант :DDD

Comment: или же делать цикл  таким образом tel-i; вконце цикла i++ и естественно поля называть таким образом tel-1, tel-2...

Comment: спасибо за ответ, первый вариант не сработает т.к. <?= echo types_render_field('tel'); ?> сразу же в ссылку даст оба значения а второй номер будет без ссылки, а второй не подходит из за неудобства, не будет же модер лазить по плагину и искать где поле добавить или удалить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено, строка преобразуется в массив, а затем он перебирается циклом. Вдруг кому пригодится

```
while (have_posts()) {
    the_post(); 
    $tel = (string)types_render_field('tel');
    $arr = explode(' ', $tel);

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) { 
        echo "<a href=\"tel: {$value}\">{$value}</a><br>";
    } 
}
```